# Yard Documentation : first line of description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation, yard

I have a problem with yard, all my text is like :

```
# General description.
#
# @param [] param ...
# @return [] description of the return
```

But the first line is **sometimes** replaced by the description of the return.
I tried without blankspace : `#General ..`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with inverting the line's order :

```
# @param [] param ...
# @return [] description of the return
# General description.
```

But i don't think it'is the better way...